# Reading on Mathematical Logic

Tags: reference-request, logic, book-recommendation

I am looking for books to read, so as to dive into mathematical logical and related disciplines like set theory, model theory, and topos theory.

I have a decent background in category theory and algebra, analysis, topology, etc. but little in explicit logic or set theory aside from the first chapter of Munkres.

Any suggestions? I am interest in topics such as para-consistency, computability, and ill-founded logics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place to start, perhaps, is here:

http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic9-2.pdf

This is a detailed annotated guide to a wide range of logic literature, at different levels of sophistication. You will be able to choose entry points to suit your background.

On non-paraconsistent logic, see in particular

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/

which gives pointers to the literature. On computability, there is much to be said for Boolos, Burgess and Jeffrey,

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computability-Logic-George-S-Boolos/dp/0521701465

I'm not sure what is meant by "ill-founded logics". For non-wellfounded set theory, see

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nonwellfounded-set-theory/

which again gives more pointers. On topos theory, I still think it is worth starting with Robert  Goldblatt's book:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Topoi-Categorial-Analysis-Logic-Mathematics/dp/0486450260

Answer (score 1):

I fondly own the following books.

**Logic**

- Peter Smith's [An Introduction To Godel's Theorems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107022843) is an excellent first introduction to logic and computability. Yes, that's the same Peter Smith whose answered your question.

**Set theory**

- Goldrei's [Classic Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412606100) is a clear and well-motivated first introduction to the subject.
- Jech's [Set Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540440852) is very highly regarded, and would be excellent for a second exposure to set theory (this is the book I really need to work through).
- Also, you mentioned an interest in topos theory. I've never studied topos theory, but I think a good starting would be Lawvere's [Sets for Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521010608) which describes basic set theory from a categorial perspective. I think this will get you "in the mindset for topoi," so to speak.