# Looking for a Great book on Proving, on Mathematical Logic in general

Tags: reference-request, logic, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a good/great book on Mathematics. More specifically one that focuses on how I should go about to prove various things, e.g. given equations what are the methods I can use in order to solve them. Generally, I mostly want a book about logic, a book that organizes one's ability to reason and not fall into traps of logical fallacies. I have found this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821820249) by David Hilbert to be more or less what I want (I think). What are your thoughts and suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some similar questions from the past (you should be probably find a few more): [Book covering introduction to mathematical proofs](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/606138), 
[Recommend a concise book on mathematical logic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768993),
or [Reading on Mathematical Logic](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526007/reading-on-mathematical-logic).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "A book that organizes one's ability to reason and not fall into traps
>   of logical fallacies."

Daniel Velleman's much admired, much recommended, [*How to Prove It*](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/mathematics/logic-categories-and-sets/how-prove-it-structured-approach-2nd-edition?format=PB) (CUP) is probably just what you are looking for. It aims, precisely, to teach techniques for writing and reading proofs.

Answer (score 1):

[Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Math and its Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0072899050)

[A Concise Introduction to Logic by Patrick J. Hurley](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0534520065)

The former is an intro to proof text and the latter is not a math text but it has considerable examples of logical fallacies.